# PHPQuery - get all links of contains specific url page

Tags: php, phpquery

I am trying to get all links of contains specific url page on a given page using PHPQuery. I am using the PHP support syntax of PHPQuery.

```
include_once 'phpQuery.php';
$url = 'http://www.phonearena.com/phones/manufacturer/';
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFile($url);

$urls = $doc['a'];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo pq($url)->attr('href') . '<br>';
}
```

The code above works . But it shows all the links
I want to show only those containing "/phones/manufacturer/".
I tried this but it shows nothing:

```
include_once 'phpQuery.php';
$url = 'http://www.phonearena.com/phones/manufacturer/';
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFile($url);

$urls = $doc['a'];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo pq($url)->attr('href:contains("/phones/manufacturer/")') . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below coding get all urls from that site,

```
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
                @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.phonearena.com/phones/manufacturer/'));

                $ahreftags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

                    foreach ($ahreftags as $tag) {
                        echo "<br/>";
                        echo $tag->getAttribute('href');
                        echo "<br/>";
                    }


exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, a little [italian guide](http://www.diodati.org/w3c/css3-wd/selettori.html#attribute-substrings), [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
include_once 'phpQuery.php';
$url = 'http://www.phonearena.com/phones/manufacturer/';
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFile($url);

$urls = $doc['a[href*="/phones/manufacturer/"]'];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo pq($url)->attr('href') . '<br>';
}
```